# Schedule shell script to display output in terminal

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, cron

I have added a shell backup script to `crontab`, and it seems to run every night, but I currently need to check the target to see that it's worked.

What would be much more helpful would be for the task to start in a new terminal window, so that the next time I logged into my machine I could immediately see the lines it's output to terminal and whether it's worked.

Is this possible?

Comment: You could alter the script to output errors or messages to a file and display that file upon login through GUI. Terminal could be done as well

Comment: Thank you, I'll use this incombination with the command below so I can see it working, and then see the log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, what you are asking is possible. If this is your crontab command:

```
* 10 * * * * doCommand

* 10 * * * * gnome-terminal -e doCommand
```

However, when the command finishes, the terminal will close. I think you need to create a log - rather than show the output in the terminal, redirect it to a file.

Original command output:

```
$ echo "This is the Command Output"
This is the Command Output
```

Redirecting to file:

```
$ echo "This is the Command Output" >> /home/USERNAME/filename.log
$ cat /home/USERNAME/filename.log
This is the Command Output
```

Of course your command wouldn't be the `echo` command - I'm guessing it would be a compressing command like `tar`.

Comment: Thank you, I'll then be able to add a command at the end of the script to open the log in gedit or similar - I'd not thought of that.

Comment: it might be useful to indicate that the `echo >> filename` should use the full path of the file. Otherwise, cron will place it in `/`, probably.

Comment: @MartinKS Yes that would display it immediately.